# Framework for GAE which use datastore (python preferred)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I love the free tier of GAE, especially Datastore.
I would like to know which frameworks that use Datastore as database.
For example, I only know

Kay Framework (not maintain anymore)
http://kay-docs.shehas.net/

Ferris 2 (not maintain anymore)
http://ferris-framework.appspot.com/docs/index.html

I prefer Python, but php or java are ok too.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, GAE kind of *is the framework*. That's part of the point.

Comment: well it is lack of CRUD, login, etc functionality so that i am looking for a ready-to-use framework

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the Google Cloud documentation, you can see that they use Flask, Django or webapp2 as the Python frameworks for providing examples related to the use of Datastore. Personally I cannot recommend any frameworks that utilize Datastore as their database.

In general for Python you can use either the REST API or the client library for a GAE application. [This article](https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/using-cloud-datastore) demonstrates the CRUD functionality implemented using the client library.

If you wish to use third party client libraries for the Datastore API, you can find a list [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries) where two Java libraries are mentioned (Objectify and Catatumbo) and one PHP library (Datastore Library for PHP).

Answer (score 0):

webapp2 is very light weight and has all the basics you would need. however if you are looking for a more "extensive" framework where you dont have to worry as much you could also look into Django (https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine)

If you like to do more yourself, like structuring your project in your own way, building your own libs = webapp2

If you want a full framework out the box in GAE Python = Django

GAE is an AMAZING service, and either way I would say you are making a great choice.

Hope this helps.